# Trouble w/Using Javascript to delete a row in MySQL

Tags: javascript

I've been modifying my site and the script is supposed to get the id value stored in $row[id] field and then call delete_printer.php?id. This logic works fine for me modifying a record yet when doing a delete I get only the first row id for all rows on that page table I try to delete. I've used this same line many times with no trouble and yet now it is broken and I cant see why.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '#del-row', function(e){  
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $("#delete-row").attr('data-id'); // get id from td element and store it in $id.
            window.location = 'printer_delete.php?id=' + id;   // call printer_delete.php with $id value to delete row.
        });
      });
     </script>
```

PHP:

```
echo "<td><a class='one glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Click Here to Edit' href='printer_update.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'></a></td>";
echo "<td><a class='one glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-row' id='delete-row' data-toggle='modal' data-placement='bottom' title='Delete Printer Record' href='#' data-target='#myModal' aria-hidden='true' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "'></a></td>";
```

This is the first time I've used the PHP in conjunction with the Javascript so I'm thinking in there lies the problem but being relatively new to JS I'm in need of some help.

Comment: Element IDs need to be unique.  You're giving the same ID (`delete-row`) to many elements in your table, and it's just finding the first one and using the `data-id` from it.  You need to change your click handler so it's more specific about the element that's been clicked.

Comment: I'm sorry could you be more specific. What has changed between modifying and deleting? Forgive if I ask the obvious.

Comment: I tell you I tried like a dozen different examples and none worked. If someone could help me out here and show me the jquery or point me to a good link that I need to get this to work I would be extremely grateful.Thanx...